# Ancestry gem with an has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I have an Items table and an associated ItemPrices table setup with a has_many association.  The ItemPrices table also has a tier_id field.

So the structure is basically

```
Item                      ItemPrices
---------                 ------------
id                        id
ancestry                  item_id
title                     tier_id
                          price
```

The Items table is setup as with has_ancestry and is working fine.

How can I grab a hierarchy of items where the itemprices are in a certain tier?

Comment: are you just trying to find a list of items that is in a given tier_id range?

Comment: @DanBradbury I'm trying to find a list of items for a given parent where the children have an itemprice in a certain tier.  So example I have Breakfast -> Eggs -> Fried Eggs and Breakfast -> Eggs -> Boiled Eggs.   Fried Eggs have a price in tier 1 and tier 2.Boiled Eggs only have a price in tier 1.    So if I'm looking at the list of items applicable to tier 1 I should see Breakfast -> Eggs -> Boiled and Fried Eggs.  If I'm looking at the list of items applicable to tier 2 then I should only see Breakfast -> Eggs -> Fried Eggs.So its an attempt to filter the list by tier_id of the association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has to be somehow like this:

Item model:

```
 has_ancestry
 has_many :item_prices

 def self.tree_with_certain_tier(tier_id)
    scoped.includes(:item_prices).collect{|item| item.item_prices.with_certain_tier(tier_id)}.arrange
 end
```

ItemPrice model:

```
 belongs_to :item
 scope :with_certain_tier, lambda {|tier_id| where(:tier_id=>tier_id) }
```

and now you can grab what you need just with

```
Item.tree_with_certain_tier(pass_certain_tier_id_here)
```

i didn't check this but it has to be correct (or at least point you in right direction)

ask if something not clear or you will get any errors. sure we will fix them quickly

Comment: getting an error on line with scope :item_prices_with_certain_tier, lambda {|tier_id| item_prices.with_certain_tier(tier_id)}

error is undefined local variable or method `item_prices' for #<Class:0x007f8d5c1e3750>

Comment: oopss... scope in item model was unnecessary... changed my answer